# Ext js dynamic loading of libraries when using iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, extjs

Good day all.
I have a big Ext js application in which I have to insert a new section which will be loaded in iframes.
To maintain the routes of Ext js, each page of the new part will be a different `view`, with a different `viewController` in which will be only the iframe that will load the page of the new application.

Now I'd like to make some cleaning in the mess, for example, all the new application pages will use some shared libraries, which will be inserted in the app.json of Extjs so they will be available for each iframe page.
but most of the scripts of these new pages will be specific of that very page, so it will be a big waste of resources if all of those scripts have to be inserted in the app.json and so they are available for every part of the application.
The idea was, is there a clean way to specify some libraries used only by a single viewController (and its iframe) and when the user change the route, everything is destroyed and the memory is cleaned?

Comment: So you mean that creating for example 2 iframes the first one should be destroyed and not hidden?

Comment: And, you need to load a js resourse only if a specific iFrame is used?

Comment: yes, exactly, the idea is that.

Comment: ok, for the second point you absolutely need Ext.Loader.loadScript

Comment: version of ext?

Comment: your iframes are Ext.windows?

Comment: ext is 5.1 and I'm using Ext.ux.iframe to load the iframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to load a specific js only if a window or frame is called, the best way is to use an Ext.Loader method called loadScript

```
Ext.loader.loadScript(url)
```

> Loads the specified script URL and calls the supplied callbacks. If this method is called before Ext#isReady, the script's load will delay the transition to ready. This can be used to load arbitrary scripts that may contain further Ext.require calls.

Also remember that your on html5! So you can use other methods to load a js script when you need it. An example:

```
System.import("yourScriptFile.js").then(function(){
   // script loaded.
});
```

If you want to load multiple files you can also use it:

```
Promise.all(["url1", "url2"].map(System.import)).then(function(){
    // loaded all here
});
```

If you need to destroy a window iframe you only need to use the method close, as you can se [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#method-close) the method close on the default case will delete the window from the dom and destroy the object from the memory.

So, in my opinion the best way is to use iframe windows, and use the close method to destroy them at the end of their life.

If you only need to use a container in which you're inserting your new html with your js scripts, you can instead call a simple .destroy() method.

Remember that there are other ways to split your project's app.js in different parts, have also a look [here](https://www.sencha.com/blog/blazingly-fast-load-times-for-apps-built-with-ext-js-and-sencha-touch/) to have an idea.